Generalized Sobolev-Morrey Embedding Theorem on Unit Sphere
By generalized Sobolev-Morrey embedding theorem, for U an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary and $k>\frac{n}{p}$, $W^{k,p}(U)$ can be embedded in $C^{k-[\frac{n}{p}]-1,\gamma}(U)$, for appropriate $\gamma$, where $W^{k,p}(U)$ is the Sobolev space. I want to know if there is a similar theorem, with $S^{n-1}$, the unit sphere instead of $U$.
